# Need help converting a BMP image to a matrix in [R]?

Tags: r, matrix, bmp, data-conversion

I'm very new to R, and I was wondering if there was a simple way to convert a BMP image to a matrix in R. Mainly, I'm looking for any package that can help. The values of each element in the matrix would correspond to colors.

Comment: if you can store your bitmap image in a png format you can use `readPNG` from `png` package otherwise you can use `readbitmap` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A search for "bmp" on the CRAN packages list pulls up `bmp` and some others, for brevity I will just use this package.

```
library(bmp)
fl <- system.file("images", "5HT1bMARCM-F000001_seg001_lsm.bmp",  package = "bmp")
b <- read.bmp(fl)
```

This object is an array, with some information about the file:

```
 str(b)
 int [1:206, 1:206, 1:3] 107 111 119 123 115 119 119 139 143 143 ...
 - attr(*, "header")=List of 13
  ..$ filesize     : num 127774
  ..$ offset       : num 54
```

It's a 3D array:

```
dim(b)
[1] 206 206   3
```

There's an `as.raster` function, which takes an optional `max` argument:

```
m <- as.raster(b, max = 255)
```

This matrix `m` is now a 2D matrix of colours (hex).

```
str(m)
 'raster' chr [1:206, 1:206] "#6B0303" "#6F0303" "#770303" ...


dim(m)
[1] 206 206
```

Let's plot this thing, we need to set up a plot and then find out it's range so we can fill the device with our image.

```
plot(1, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
usr <- par("usr")
rasterImage(m, usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4])
```

Your needs will depend on the storage options used by your BMP file and on which software you use to read it.

[image: Basic image plot from R bmp package]

There are other options, with the `readbitmap` package and with `rgdal` (and perhaps that via `raster`), but it will depend on what you can install on your machine.

Comment: OK, so I started using read.bmp to try some of this out. I made a 16x16 image, and it's all black and white. I interpreted it through readPNG first (same image, but as a png file), and the values I got were all decimals under 1 (for the black pixels) or 1 for the white ones. When I saved the same image as a monochrome bmp, it wouldn't read it through read.bmp. Any ideas?

Comment: this is not good information for someone to help you, why not flesh out what you've done and what you expect in detail? See here for a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example